# Strange loud noise coming out of my VW passat 2008 fsi

Tags: vw, passat

I hear this whining noise coming out of my car. I don't know if it's the belt or the fan. It's reduces when I accelerate.the noise doesn't stop until I turn of the engine or accelerate.

Comment: Likely to be the belt, especially if it is a squeaky sort of noise.

Comment: Could be a bearing on one of your ancillaries, if it is more of a whine than a squeal.

Comment: pop the hood and have a look at the belts, if it is worn you will see small bites missing or cracks or tears.  Does you issue get real loud when you crank the wheel to full lock at a standstill and slowly inch forward?  If so it's definitely belts.  If all the belts look good I would then follow HandyHowie's instructions and start checking bearings.

Answer (score 3):

I went to the mechanic and he changed the ventil unit and the sound stopped.  Thanx guys

Comment: Award yourself the answer and I'll upvote it later.  Can you explain what the 'ventilation unit' is?  Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: It's a round thing with a pipe. http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12t8LIpXXXXbEXpXXq6xXFXXX2/100-Volkswagen-Genuine-font-b-Oil-b-font-Separator-PCV-Valve-Assembly-For-VW-Passat-font.jpg